# Flutter: How to let trailing icon move with largeTitle?

Tags: flutter, trailing

I want to add a Icon on the right of largeTitle.And I hope that the icon can move with the largeTitle,But now the icon on the trailing on the top-right of the screen,not move with the largeTitle .What can I do to solve the problem?

```
new CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
       largeTitle: Text('More',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: 
       FontWeight.bold),),
       trailing: Icon(Icons.search,size: 24,color: Colors.black54,),
     ),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XySxv.png)

Comment: Please describe what do you mean by move with the largeTitle? How does the largeTitle move and to where?

Comment: When the page scrolls, the largeTitle will change from the small-title (on the top-center of the page) to the large-title, but after becoming the large-title, the title will be from the top of the page to the left of the page, I hope that the right Icon can always be on the right side of the title, regardless of whether the title is at the top or on the left. But now Icon's position doesn't move, and when the title is on the top of the page,The icon will be on the right of the page,However when the title on the left(Shows as largeTitle),the icon is on the top-right of the title.

Comment: did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

try Align Widget..

```
   new CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
     largeTitle: Text('More',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: 
     FontWeight.bold),),
     trailing: Align(
     alignment:Alignment.bottomLeft
     child : ICON(Icons.search,size: 24,color: Colors.black54,)
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: When the page scrolls, the largeTitle will change from the small-title (on the top-center of the page) to the large-title, but after becoming the large-title, the title will be from the top of the page to the left of the page, I hope that the right Icon can always be on the right side of the title, regardless of whether the title is at the top or on the left. But now Icon's position doesn't move, and when the title is on the top of the page,The icon will be on the right of the page,However when the title on the left(Shows as largeTitle),the icon is on the top-right of the title.